# Result conflict in mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i am facing a strange issue, if i am checking the mysql query with PHP then i didn't get the exact result according to mysql query.

But the same query if i run then i get the expected result, here is mysql query:

```
SELECT id, follow_up_datetime, followed_by, follow_up_status, case_time_zone, description, case_id
FROM case_note
WHERE TYPE LIKE '%follow-up-open%'
AND (
    follow_up_datetime LIKE '%2013-01-08%'
    OR date( follow_up_datetime ) < '2013-01-08'
)
AND follow_up_status <= '1'
GROUP BY case_id
ORDER BY case_id DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

the result of this query is :

[image: mysql_result]

but when i use the same query with php then i get the the wrong ids:
**PHP**

```
//current date is "2013-01-08";
$follow_q = "SELECT id, follow_up_datetime, followed_by, follow_up_status, case_time_zone, description, case_id
                 FROM case_note
                 WHERE `type` LIKE '%follow-up-open%'
                 AND (
                 follow_up_datetime LIKE '%$current_date%'
                 OR date(follow_up_datetime) < '$current_date'
                 )
                 AND follow_up_status <= '1' 
                 GROUP BY case_id 
                 ORDER BY case_id DESC";
$follow_r = mysql_query($follow_q) or die('Error in Query!<br />' . mysql_error());
```

this query providing me the id's like `53, 84, 47, 36`.

last three id's are correct but the first is not correct. i want first id is `139`. Can anyone please help to find out the exact problem?

**UPDATE**: here i have update the result of id `53`

[image]

Comment: What does `$current_date` hold?

Comment: Assuming that follow_up_datetime is a temporal type, then LIKE isn't a good way to extract partial matches from it.  You'd be better to use the DATE function to get just the date portion.  If it's not temporal, than why not? :)  Also, it's not advisable to be using mysql_* as those functions are deprecated in all but name.  Use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: @JanHančič as i shown in comment that is `2013-01-08`

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Are you also sure that you are querying the same database in both cases?

Comment: @JanHančič yes i am `100%` sure

Comment: Your queries are not the same. This part: `AND (
    follow_up_datetime LIKE '%2013-01-08%'
    OR date( follow_up_datetime ) < '2013-01-08'
)`

Comment: @JanHančič ya, but the same result getting

Comment: Sorry what? Your question resolves around not getting the same results and now you're saying that they are the same? I'm confused.

Comment: @JanHančič i mean to say the PHP provide the same first id that is `53` but according to SQL query i want `139`

Comment: Just fix what Jan told you and it will work.

Comment: @Shomz i tried everything but didn't get the exact result :(, with `date()` and without `date()`

Comment: Can we see the datas contained on the  row 53 ?

Comment: You didn't set the `` arround the `type` field in your initial request (line 3)

Comment: @GillesHemmerlé i have updated the result of `53` id, i tried with the `type` but not helpful.

Comment: Can you echo your query?

Comment: @Shomz after echoing i have got the query and then i run it into the mysql and that time i got the different result that i discussed here.

Comment: That might be a good place to start debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips concerning your query itself:

Your `follow_up_datetime` should be a type [timestamp or datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

You don't need the `LIKE` operator in your date condition.

```
DATE( `follow_up_datetime` ) = '2013-01-08' 
OR 
DATE( `follow_up_datetime` ) < '2013-01-08'
```

This can be shortened into

```
DATE( `follow_up_datetime` ) <= '2013-01-08'
```

If you always compare to the current date, you can use `CURRENT_DATE`

```
DATE( `follow_up_datetime` ) <= CURRENT_DATE
```

Don't compare a col of type int to a string which will force MySQL to cast all values of the col `follow_up_status` to string.

```
`follow_up_status` <= 1
```

Are you sure you need `LIKE` for the type condition?

```
`type` = 'follow_up_open'
```

Would be much faster.

**PHP documentation about the MySQL extension:**

> This extension is **deprecated** as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API guide](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

---

**EDIT:**

Just realized you `GROUP BY case_id`.
If both, id `53` and id `139` have the same `case_id` MySQL needs to know which row can be discarded. If you don't give this information, one of the two rows is discarded more or less randomly.

To work around this problem use a [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//group-by-functions.html#function_min). in your case `MIN()` would deliver the desired result.

The whole query cleaned up using PHP [heredoc notation](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$follow_q = <<< EOQ
    SELECT 
        MIN( `id` ) AS `id`,
        `follow_up_datetime`,
        `followed_by`,
        `follow_up_status`,
        `case_time_zone`,
        `description`,
        `case_id`
    FROM
        `case_note`
    WHERE
        `type` = 'follow-up-open'
         AND
        `follow_up_datetime` <= '{$current_date}'
        AND
        `follow_up_status <= 1
    GROUP BY 
        `case_id`
    ORDER BY 
        `case_id` DESC
EOQ;
```

Comment: in terms of your result there is no difference, no matter how you submit the query and receive the result. If you are getting a different result the query you submit in your PHP script is different. What's the output of `echo $follow_q;`? Are you sure your query runs against the same database in both cases?

Comment: yes i am sure about everything, actually i don't want to show the duplicate `case_id` if i remove the `group by` the i get the result `53, 139, ..` respectivally, but when i use `group by` then in DB i get `139, ..` respectivally and with php  i get `53, ..` respectivally :(

Comment: wow, awesome :) but i get the expected result with `MAX()` instead of `MIN()`. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be from `follow_up_status <= '1'`. If the column is a numeric type, you should pass the value as a number, not string. Try:

```
follow_up_status <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I would [error_log()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) the $follow_q variable and then copy and paste that query into MySQL and see if it returns the same or wrong results because maybe your $current_date variable is wrong.